# ddply with chunks from multiple data frames

Tags: r, plyr

How can ddply (and similar functions) work with multiple data frames.

For example, I have one dataframe with information about cars in a family

```
car <- data.frame(name=c('aaa','aaa','bbb'), cars=c('honda','chevy','datsun'))
```

and a second dataframe with family members

```
 people <- data.frame(name=c('aaa','bbb','bbb'), age=c(25,18,33))
```

I would like to apply a function

```
 neatfun <- function( car_chunk, people_chunk){ analysis with age and type of cars}
```

to the corresponding chunks of car and people, something along the lines of

```
 analysis <- ddply( list(car,people), "name", neatfun)
```

where ddply would split the list of dataframes by name and then pass the corresponding chunks of each dataframe to the neatfun function.

At the moment, I'm willing to assume that every "name" appears appears in all data frames so I don't have to worry about families with cars (but no people) or with people (but no cars).

Thanks

Comment: the easiest way would be newdf<-merge(car, people, by="name"), and then run on the newdf

Comment: after merging as @jeremycg showed you could use `ddply` like this `ddply(newdf, .(name), colwise(neatfun))`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you mean by 'some analysis', I can see a few ways to proceed. Start off by combining your data into a single dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
> df <- left_join(car, people)
Joining by: "name"
> df
  name   cars age
1  aaa  honda  25
2  aaa  chevy  25
3  bbb datsun  18
4  bbb datsun  33
```

Then use dplyr operations to do analysis.

```
processed_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  ## do analysis here
  ## e.g. summarise, mutate, filter, top_n
```

If you have something a little more complex to do, and you want to have a function that say takes in a dataframe, does some stuff to it, and spits out a new dataframe, you can write the function that does it, split your data into a list, apply the function to each piece, and then either keep it in a list or if it makes sense bind them all together.

This is assuming we have the same df from above, a joined dataframe. (The `merge` option listed above should do the same thing as a `left_join` in `dplyr`.

```
df_func <- function(df){  ## take in a dataframe, do stuff, return a dataframe
  ## some analysis
  return(df_new)
}
df_list <- split(df, df$name)  ## make a list of dataframes, 
                               ## where each element is a dataframe with the same name
df_new_list <- lapply(df_list, FUN = df_func)  ## apply function to each element
total_list <- rbind_all(df_new_list) ## put all the elements into a single dataframe
                                     ## rbind_all is a dplyr tool.
                                     ## otherwise you can use
total_list <- do.call(rbind, df_new_list)
```

Comment: The two data frames don't necessarily have the same number of rows in each chunk, and nor is a left_join "sensible" as there is no correspondence between any of the rows in the two data frames other than the two data frames have different types of information about each family.

Comment: Hm, could you elaborate? As far as I can tell, join and merge do the same thing (and if every name in one dataframe is present in the other dataframe, then there's no difference between a left_join and an inner join). A quick test on your data shows merge and left_join give the same results. Also, I don't think it matters if the dataframes don't have an equal number of rows, this should work regardless.

Comment: I don't need (nor want the data frame chunks to be joined). All I need is a way to create chunks from two different data frames split by the same grouping variable, and pass the pairs of chunks to a function much like ddply passes a single chunk from a single dataframe at a time.  The function cannot be decomposed in doing a ddply each data frame and merging the results together. A join/merge makes life difficult because now some rows in some chunks are duplicated when merging with the other data frame.

Comment: For example, I could use "split" to create a list of chunks from each data frame, but as far as I can tell, there is no simple way to ensure that first element of the list of chunks from each data frame now "match" unless both data frames are consistent in the values of the grouping variable. Then I could loop through the lists using the first element of each list, the second element of each list, etc, but is there a more elegant way?